# Google special SERP entry for Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, google, seo

Wow, have you seen the new [search engine result page](https://www.google.com/search?ei=h5glWpvhOoWzjwSI7KaIDQ&q=xpath%20namespaces&oq=xpath%20namespaces) entry for Stack Overflow hits in Google:

[image]

And when there are multiple answers:

[image]

I am not sure if this has been rolled-out globally or if this is just an A-B test, but I think this is an excellent improvement for the UI to our favorite Q/A site!

I cannot find an announcement of this. Is anyone seeing this or have further information?

---

@JeremyBanks, it looks like *Best Answer* is indeed the selected answer, not the necessarily the one with the most votes:

[image]

Comment: I Google seem to be A/B testing this... You probably need to figure out how to make other visitors to be in the same group as you to see what you are talking about... (Also not really sure what you want to discuss)

Comment: If this is in A/B testing what are we supposed to do/think about it other then it looks cool?

Comment: This is entirely on Google, and has nothing to do with Stack Overflow or the technology used to operate such. So... How is your question on topic here? Yes, it's about Google displaying the site, but not about the site or anything the site does. This reads very much like a general forum, "Hey, guys, check out this cool thing!" style post...

Comment: Of course it's entirely on Google.  Of course I'm not looking for an "answer".  This is Meta, and here we sometimes *discuss* the UI to SO.  Given that SO's own search weakness is a common topic, and that many here deliberately or inadvertantly use Google as their entryway to SO, I thought there may be interest in seeing and possibly discussing this development.  If you're not so inclined, feel free to sit this one out.  Hopefully you've at least appreciated seeing that this may be coming.

Comment: I wonder if their "best" answer is based on what's accepted or what has the most votes. Either way, this is a big upgrade from their uncontextualized quotes.

Comment: This is not the first time Google has been experimenting, see [Is Google doing something new with this site's data?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268732)

Comment: @JeremyBanks: Looks like answer marked best is the selected answer, not necessarily the answer with the most votes.   I've added a screenshot to show this.  Cool that they're tracking and display both dimensions separately.

Comment: @MartijnPieters:  Close as duplicate?  Their latest effort is substantially improved over that old approach.  Moreover, do you really want to squelch discussion here?  I'd think you'd want to celebrate the effort and amplify my attempt to elevate its exposure, not bury it.

Comment: @kjhughes: the answer is still the same: This is an *experiment Google is running*, and they are using information that has been there all along, for years now.

Comment: @kjhughes: I am not part of the A/B test group, for example. **Until this is mainstream** this is not yet something to celebrate.

Comment: @kjhughes: Google has been running these experiments for a long, long time now, I'm not holding my breath that this one will be made final either.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Take a longer term, bigger picture perspective.  It's a good development for SO.  It merits support and exposure, not guarded cynicism.

Comment: @kjhughes: last but not least, your question was *already closed by the community*. At least I gave you a duplicate link for more info.

Comment: @kjhughes: there is **nothing to expose yet**. You are jumping the gun. Give them the feedback they ask for (see the duplicate), and **if the experiment is a success**, then perhaps it'll be elevated to a permanent fixture. We can't do anything else until then.

Comment: @kjhughes: as for the cynicism: I've seen Google experiment with the Schema.org data for over 5 years now. Yes this is the best of those experiments so far, but until it is actually rolled out world-wide, it is not yet an official feature, and the cynicism will be kept firmly in place.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Friendly suggestion: Re-read your comments from the point of view of the Google developers who've implemented this and the managers who've championed it.  Now, go back and re-write your comments and answer to be supportive because it's a good direction that's worth encouraging.  This is my last recommendation on this topic.  Thank you.

Comment: @kjhughes: I work at a similarly large social media company. I can assure you that the Google managers and engineers will be fine with or without my comments here. They'll hold their own council. My primary concern is managing the expectations of the Stack Overflow community.

Comment: @MartijnPieters this is not a duplicate.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: care to add more motivations other than just a blanket statement?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I don't think that other question should be used whenever there is new experiment of Google feature that affect SO search results. Each should be on its own. Maybe it's off topic due to not being really part of Stack Overflow but rather Google, but that's another story.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: These experiments have been running for years now. We really don't need a new post every time someone ends up in the test group.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I disagree, but over here you call the shots. I did what I can,there's nothing more to do or say. At least OP got clear answer to their question, dupe or not.

Comment: **Moderator note**: This question is either off-topic (we discuss Stack Overflow here, not Google's UI), or a duplicate (this is an A/B experiment that Google has periodically been running for the past 5 years now). I've re-duped because I feel the previous post covers the what and how, including how you can give feedback to Google.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: By re-duping, you've wiped out at least 2 re-open votes, and those people are now blocked from casting new re-open votes.  Are such heavy-handed, anti-community methods really warranted here?  Again, this move to improve the primary way the world comes to StackOverflow deserves to be celebrated and encouraged, not opposed and buried via overbearing moderation.

Comment: @kjhughes assuming this question got reopened, what kind of answer do you expect to get that is different than the one from the duplicate link? (I'm still in doubt whether to vote to reopen or not)

Comment: If I saw that experiment (unlikely) I would click feedback and state the accepted answer isn't the "best" answer. No answer is the best, they usually suck less than others.

Comment: My answer below should help explain why this is both on topic and not a dupe: the experiment has a potential attribution problem that warrants discussion here, and makes this distinct from at least some prior experiments. The next experiment may have different (or no) problems and need different discussion. Additionally, there may be other issues related to this experiment. Ideally, each one would have it's own question... but we see again the Stack Overflow platform isn't exactly well-suited for discussion (but dogfooding is important, yo), so one question on the experiment may still be best.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

This is an ongoing experiment that Google is running. They contacted us some time ago and let us know they were interested in running an experiment that showed additional information from our site including answer snippets. At the time they were going to focus it on the mobile app and web experience, but the desktop experience is also included in this round of testing.

While Google doesn't need our permission for this, they have been forthcoming and are keeping us in the loop on which experiments they're running, and will be sharing data back on the results of the experiments.  We will continue to strongly advocate for what we think is best for our users, which includes steering them away from experiments or results that we feel is a detriment to new user and community engagement in the ecosystem.

Comment: Greatly appreciate your response.  Would love to hear your thoughts on whether you like what you see in this experiment so far and what results would constitute a successful outcome.  Thank you.

Comment: Seems this isn't the [only experimental result of this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/360533/google-search-results-now-listing-all-so-questions-under-one-result).

Answer (score 18):

Seems like it violates the Stack Overflow [attribution requirements](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/) by not showing the usernames. Otherwise, I think it's pretty awesome.

If Stack Overflow wants to grant Google an exception to those requirements, it might be a good idea to publish the justification for the exception. Sure, "Because they're Google" might be about it, and that might be enough, but this reminds me of one aspect of the problem we have right now helping people understand why Net Neutrality is important. If only established players can afford the fast lane (or get granted attribution exceptions), it makes it harder for newer, smaller, and potentially better competition to ever get any traction.

The other part of this that comes to mind is that, by only showing snippets, Google feels like they have a fair use claim... and that's likely true for many questions and answers. Some of the shorter posts, though, they're likely reproducing nearly the entire post, and without attribution that's a problem.

Comment: If attribution *were* required (I don’t think it is), stating the username wouldn’t be sufficient. 1) The license has to be stated, too (the linked blog post [misses to mention this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225486/193139)). 2) If the answer itself contains licensing information (e.g., because it’s an adaptation), this information would have to be stated, too.

Answer (score -7):

Please downvote this answer if you find that Google feature useful.

I **DO NOT LIKE** this feature:

- Provided space is not enough to fit fully 99.9% of SO answers, I have to visit result page to use it **anyway**.
- Ability to select the answer (that fancy horizontal scroll) on the Google page is useless due to lack of space again, I'll have to visit page **anyway**.
- Information like "best answer" and number of votes also **useless**, we (we = users of SO) aren't using only those to find answers.
- With this feature there are **less search result** on the page, I have to scroll more.
- The feature override available earlier "see more results from stackoverflow" which I find **very useful** (but it's not there anymore).

I just want to to inform SO stuff about it (upvote if you hate it too) and maybe they will deal with Google. What Google doing is ridiculously stupid, but will they listen to me?