# Google search results now listing all SO questions under one result?

Tags: discussion, search, google

I've been away for a couple of days, just come back needed a quick answer to a problem, ran a Google search and I expected a SO result, which I did, kinda:

[image]

Oh a page that would of been full of SO answers now only contains one and some sub pages.

Quick check again, same result:

[image]

It appears that Google have updated their algorithm/results (**or something has been changed on the pages?**) and this is going to have a serious detrimental effect on SO results. Being as the SO search is pretty woeful ([and has been for quite some time](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308398/what-progress-has-been-made-recently-toward-improving-stack-overflow-search-resu)) and this site relies so heavily on Google to crawl it's content, this seems like a major issue.

Are you guys aware of this? Do you foresee it causing problems? Is it expected? etc.

I'm logged into Google using a google account if that makes a difference.

Comment: Google seems to be experimenting with several formats for Q/A sites: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/360212/google-special-serp-entry-for-stack-overflow

Comment: This format is not really new though, it's used for a lot of sites, especially forums.

Comment: Just caught me off guard really, it looked totally different to how it looked on Friday when I last logged in

Comment: I think the question linked by @rene covers pretty much everything here. I'll close as a dupe

Comment: I liked this feature tbh, 5 guaranteed links from SO is nut. "more results from stackoverflow" is time saver. It seems google keep experimenting as of today they rolled back feature in duplicate which **disable** that "more results".

Answer (score -2):

I think this is a good movement of Google. Still you can see the first few result of Google at a glance....

Then if we want to just SO results, we had to search something like `site:stackoverflow.com my query`. But now you we can easily click the `more results from Stackoverflow.com` link.

Comment: That's not really what I'm asking.

Comment: @Liam "It appears that Google have updated their algorithm/results (or something has been changed on the pages?) and this is going to have a serious detrimental effect on SO results."... Why did you said that this is going to have a serious detrimental effect on SO results? How this happens? Because still you can see the first few results on Google

Comment: My questions (the bits with the `?`) are *or something has been changed on the pages?....Are you guys aware of this? Do you foresee it causing problems? Is it expected? etc*