# Links to answers showing up in Google results

Tags: discussion

I was searching through Google, and clicked on a link to a SO question. The weird thing was, it took me straight to an answer instead of to the question like it normally does.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1131458) is the link (`https://stackoverflow.com/q/1131458`), which redirects to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131430/are-generators-threadsafe/1131458#1131458) (`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131430/are-generators-threadsafe/1131458#1131458`); an answer.

I've never noticed this happening before. This link is using `/q/` instead of `/questions/` like most other links.

Are `/q/` links supposed to be showing up in results? Interestingly, Google can only find 301 such links if you search for `site:stackoverflow.com/q/` (it shows  1.7M initially, but then drops when you go to page 11 ¯\_(ツ)_/¯).

Comment: After some testing, Google seems to cap how many results it'll show. `site:stackoverflow.com/questions/` only goes to page 14. Maybe `/q/` are more common than I though and I just never noticed them before?

Comment: Google also indexed links to answer explicitly: `site:stackoverflow.com/a/`

Comment: "instead of to the question like it normally does" - well my mileage varies, I'm used to being sent to answers. And I love that because that's exactly what I'm looking for when I'm searching using Google.

Comment: This is probably [another one of Google's experiments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268731/is-google-doing-something-new-with-this-sites-data/268732) with [how they display results from Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/360212/google-special-serp-entry-for-stack-overflow/360273).